# Why doesn't unique_ptr::reset have overloads that take a deleter?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Is there a reason `unique_ptr::reset` doesn't have overloads that take a `const deleter&` and `deleter&&` to match its constructors that take those as a second argument?

The stored deleter in `unique_ptr` would be copy assigned or move assigned with the argument from `reset`. If the deleter is noncopyable or nonmovable, calling the corresponding overload of the `reset` wouldn't compile. This seems like it would be consistent behavior with the constructors.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I thought about adding that but you can get the equivalent functionality with a move assignment operator:

```
ptr = unique_ptr<T, D>(new T(another_value), D(another_state));
```

So I opted for not saying the same thing with `reset` in the interest of keeping the API reasonably small.

**Update**

And I live and learn...

The syntax can actually be much simpler than what I show above:

```
ptr = {new T(another_value), D(another_state)};
```

Comment: +1 for having the only _authoritative_ answer to a 'why' question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner and more consistent with shared_ptr if there was a reset function? For me, it feels especially cleaner when you have a custom deleter function. For example: `ptr = unique_ptr<int, void(*)(int*)>(new_raw_ptr, deleter_function);` vs `ptr.reset(new_raw_ptr, deleter_function);`. Or even better if we could keep the same deleter_function, so it would be like: `ptr.reset(new_raw_ptr);`.

Comment: @felipou:  The latter works.  For the former, here is how *you* can make it happen:  http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#submit_issue

Comment: What the... I was so sure I had tried that already! And I really thought I had read the docs... Well, thanks a lot for the info! :) And thanks a lot for the submit HOWTO also! I'm not sure I'm prepared for that right now, since apparently I can't even use the library correctly, but I'll definitely think about it from now on! :)

Answer (score 4):

Because the deleter is stored in the object at construction. As the deleter type is a template argument, after construction there is no way to "convert" the class to use another one.

Comment: So, invoke the copy assignment operator or move assignment operator respectively. If your deleter doesn't have an acceptable accessible one it wont compile.

Comment: Isn't that overengineering a class that is to serve a simple purpose?

Comment: You can copy construct and move construct - why would adding the ability to copy assign and move assign be overengineering? This seems like a consistent complexity level with the other functionality to me (that is to say, not complex at all)

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz: On the contrary; the class is both extremely simple *and* very flexible. By contrast, something like `shared_ptr`, whose type does *not* depend on the deleter, is a real monster by comparison.

Comment: Also, I'm not proposing you would "transform" the deleter to a new type. If your deleter type you're passing isn't convertible to the deleter type in the `unique_ptr` it won't compile - exactly the same way it works for the constructors that take a `const deleter&` and `deleter&&`.

Comment: @Kerrek, well that was exactly what I meant :P

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz There is explicitly support for stateful deleters. I see no reason why you wouldn't want to 'reset' the deleter when you 'reset' the object. I just realized I can do what I want already: I would first call `reset` and then call `get_deleter` and I can copy assign to it, move assign to it, or do anything else I want to do with it.

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz, I don't find your argument make any sense.  You basically argued two things: 1) deleter type can't be changed; 2) same object should have the same deleter.  These two are valid but how could you never thought of another use case that deleter is stateful, so it is totally valid and desirable that reset can take a new object as well as new deleter?  You never thought about this?